# Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $G \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ measurable such that $m^*(G \setminus E) < \varepsilon.$ Show that $E$ is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be such set that for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a measurable set $G \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $E \subset G$ and $m^*(G \setminus E) < \varepsilon.$ Show that $E$ is measurable.

I'm given the definition that $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is measurable if $$m^*(A) = m^*(A\cap E) + m^*(A \cap E^c)$$ holds for all $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

So let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Now since $G$ is measurable I have that $$m^*(A)=m^*(A \cap G) + m^*(A \cap G^c)$$ and since $E \subset G$ I have the following inequality $$m^*(A)=m^*(A \cap G) + m^*(A \cap G^c) \ge m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \cap E)$$ I'm stuck here and not sure how to proceed. What should I consider next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $m^{*}(A\cap E^{c}) \leq m^{*}(A\cap G^{c})+m^{*} (G\setminus E) <  m^{*}(A\cap G^{c})+\epsilon$.

Comment: How did you come up with $m^{*}(A\cap E^{c}) \leq m^{*}(A\cap G^{c})+m^{*} (G\setminus E)$?

Comment: @Danlo $A \cap E^{c} \subset (A \cap G^{c})\cup (G \setminus E))$

Comment: So I have that $m^*(A) < m^*(A  \cap E) + m^*(A \setminus G) + \varepsilon$?

Comment: $$m^*(A)=m^*(A \cap G) + m^*(A \cap G^c) \ge m^*(A \cap E) + m^*(A \cap E^{c})-\epsilon$$